# GKE ingress fails when adding DNS required in ingress.yaml

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Calling all GKE ingress experts… can anyone help me understand why I get the following error with the shown ingress deployment:

error:

```
response 404 (backend NotFound), service rules for [ / ] non-existent
```

yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neg-demo-ing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: neg-demo-ing.domain.io
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: neg-demo-svc # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
            servicePort: 80 # Should match the port used by the Service
```

however, when i don't include the host the ip returns the expected service in the browser

this works:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neg-demo-ing
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: neg-demo-svc # Name of the Service targeted by the Ingress
    servicePort: 80 # Should match the port used by the Service
```

however i want to deploy a dns entry within the yaml that will get picked up by the external-dns service

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused because of a DNS / Nameserver config, resulting in the certificate generation failing and the above behaviour